# mach/shock diamonds in blender

Tags: rendering, effects, photorealism

I'm working on a jet in blender.
While thinking about the final scene, I wondered if there was a way to create schock diamonds(also known as Mach diamonds, Mach disks, Mach rings, donut tails or thrust diamonds) in blender.

Hopefully somebody can help, I haven't found anything online.

[image: test afterburner]

[Wikipedia link on shock diamond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_diamond)
[image: Lockheed Martin F-22A Raptor]
picture from wikipedia
[image: F22 with mach diamonds from Tom Clancy's H.A.W.X]
picture from Tom Clancy's H.A.W.X

thanks for any tips.

tags: mach, schock, diamond, jet, exhaust, afterburner, engine, Physical phenomena

edit: added some pictures,

Comment: Still image or animation?

Comment: a still image will suffice for my project

Comment: Ok, I'll try to make an answer later that day.

Comment: so, nobody has any help?

Comment: well seems to be a dead question

Comment: The two pictures show different exhaust types. Have a look at this tutorial I think you should be able to adapt it to your needs https://www.blendernation.com/2018/06/10/tutorial-zooming-light-titles/

Comment: I can make a basic exhaust  with that, thanks. but I'm struggling with the exhaust pattern. best idea that I have is some sorta texture.

Comment: Some guy sort of cracked this for 2.8 and has been selling the diamonds for a while. They're rightfully proud of themselves. https://blendermarket.com/products/alien-propulsion-engines-and-exhausts--sci-fi-corridor

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue a while back.

First, [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4p7B4h7eOdA) gave me the general idea on how to achieve a basic exaust

However, since you just need to make an image it should be easier

---

I came up with two ways to do it:

### 1. The fast way

- Create a exhaust shaped cilinder (I used a cylinder, scaled down one face and welded it to an half sphere on the other end), a toroid and a small UV sphere.
- Join the toroid and the sphere, then add an **Array Modifier** to them (or just duplicate them many times).
- Play with the materials using the **Emission Shader** in the *Volume* socket of the **Output Node** (a **Volume BSDF** with 0 density and *Emission* turned on will do the trick as well): the toroids and spheres will have a simple orange color with some noise, the material of the main shape is shown in the next method

[image]

---

### 2. The long and (probably) better way

This method requires a bit of math knowledge, so be warned

- create the main exhaust shape described before without the toroids and spheres
- make this material

[image]

The fist color ramp (the purple/blu one) is creating the main exhuast material, the second is creating the rings. The main idea behind this material is to create cylinders in the exhaust shape that you will then use to model the entire thing.

It can be fairly complex if you don't like math or if you are not experienced with Blender, but with some tweaking the results will be awesome, and you can make it more versatile as well

---

As you can see, these are not complete ideas: it's 1 AM in the morning here so I don't have time to finish them now.

You still need to add some horizontal noise and the little balls in the second method, and you need to tweak the materials to make them look good (I just tryied to explain you the methods, I'm not doing it for you)

---

### Don't panic!

Here you can download the .blend file ;P

[image]